# htaccess 301 redirect issue with url variables

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

If I use this code, it's successful:

```
Redirect 301 /products.php http://website.com.au/product_123.php
```

But if I do this, it isn't:

```
Redirect 301 /products.php?id=123 http://website.com.au/product_123.php
```

Note the variable in the url is what's causing it to fail.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this? I really need the urls variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't put query string parameters in the source URI path of the `Redirect` directive. You'll have to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
RewriteRule ^/?product\.php$ http://website.com.au/product_123.php? [L,R=301]
```

Or to make it more general:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?product\.php$ http://website.com.au/product_%1.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect, i didnt know about that restriction on 301's with htaccess files

Comment: Actually Jon, I am having one more issue.

I also need /products.php?id=123&a=b as a link, but i only need the first bit of the urls (id=123) and I want to ignore the rest - is that possible? What would I change

Comment: I guessm talking about a wildcard after the id=123

Comment: @cardi777 for the first rule, you can change the condition's regex to `^id=123($|&)` and it should match exactly `id=123` and ignore any other query string params