# Changes in htaccess file for url redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change my website url dynamically. Please tell me If there is any way is redirect my url through htaccess file.

Like: my url is: www.abc.com/master.php?id=3 to www.abc.com/master.php?id=laptop

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988815/htaccess-301-redirect-issue-with-url-variables

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your urls like: `http://www.abc.com/master/3/` and then create a .htaccess file with following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Warning: it's untested code so it may not be fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure! you can use this one also

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule master.php?id=$(.*)\$ master.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Like: my url is: www.abc.com/master.php?id=3 to www.abc.com/master.php?id=laptop`

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(master\.php)\?(id=)3[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2=laptop [R=302,L]
```