# Can't get a 301 redirect to work

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect old website's urls to a new one. Old website was build using ASP.NET, new one with PHP. I'm having issue with query string parameters. Found this solution but couldn't get it to work:
[htaccess 301 redirect issue with url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988815/htaccess-301-redirect-issue-with-url-variables)

Here's a code example:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cat=איזמלים,_מפרקים_ומוטות_הרמה($|&)
    RewriteRule ^products\.aspx$ /index.php/he/קטלוג-מוצרים/category/12-איזמלים,-מפרקים-ומוטות-הרמה?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Here are the original URLS:

Old URL: [http://www.wizner.co.il/products.aspx?cat=איזמלים,_מפרקים_ומוטות_הרמה](http://www.wizner.co.il/products.aspx?cat=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D,_%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%94)

New URL: [http://www.wizner.co.il/index.php/he/קטלוג-מוצרים/category/12-איזמלים,-מפרקים-ומוטות-הרמה](http://www.wizner.co.il/index.php/he/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/category/12-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D,-%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%94)

Can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: change `?&%{QUERY_STRING}` to <space> `[R=301,QSA]`

Comment: Thank you for your replay. That didn't work. I'm still getting the same result.