# change path by RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I want to open this url:

```
http://www.example.com/quiz/en/my-love/123232
```

and show:

```
http://www.example.com/quiz/en/my-love?result=123232
```

how to do it by .htaccess and RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer of google about this :

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, it wouldn't work in your case, you are right.

I think you could take a look at this one : [htaccess 301 redirect issue with url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988815/htaccess-301-redirect-issue-with-url-variables)

Or for docs :

- [github .htaccess](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)
- [Apache documentation mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

**RE-EDIT**

Following the documentation :

```
RewriteRule ^/quiz/en/my-love?result=([^/d]+)/?$ quiz/en/my-love/$1 [L,QSA]
```

/!\ not tested

Comment: but en,my-love,123232 it's variables and not constants... possible to do it?

Comment: Ok, you're right, didn't read well your question. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this inform if any issue.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)/(\d+)$ $1/$2/$3.php?result=$4
```