# HTAccess Redirect 301 Wordpress Search Result

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I do have some Problems with a 301 Redirect in Wordpress... 
My problem is that I need to redirect (301) a page from a search-result to a new Domain.
The original URL is like 
www.myOLDdomain.com/page/10/s=some + words 
And this should redirect to 
www.myNEWdomain.com/tag/some-words/
I use this code in my htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine on <br />
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \s=some + words <br />
RewriteRule /page/10/$ https:www.myNEWdomain.com/tag/some-words/? [L,R=301]
```

I found this code above in this Thread:
[htaccess 301 redirect issue with url variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988815/htaccess-301-redirect-issue-with-url-variables)

Thank you for assistance and advise.
Best regards Jörg

Comment: is it worked? do you need any answer?

Comment: Hello Hamid, sorry, but it still does not work. I even tried to escape the "s" - but it took no effect.

Comment: The URL you have shown does not have a query string. Did you actually mean `/page/10/?s=some + words`? And the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a /, when the whole thing is configured in .htaccess, that has been stripped off at that point already.

Comment: The `<br />` are not actually in your .htaccess, right?

Comment: Hi 04FS
yepp - there ar no "<br />" in my htaccess :)

Comment: And you re right too, the url is /page/10/?=something. I tried so many Codes I found on the web... even the complete URL. But it all didn't work...I don not have any ideas, what might be the fault I'm stepping in every time....